# Retrieve unique counts in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm looking to create a formula that counts the number of sign ups for a given day.  My input data is based off an event log, and looks something like this:

#### AccountName | SignUpDay | EventLogged

acct1 | 06/01/2016 | 06/01/2016

acct1 | 06/01/2016 | 06/05/2016

acct2 | 06/01/2016 | 06/02/2016

acct3 | 06/01/2016 | 06/04/2016

acct3 | 06/01/2016 | 06/06/2016

acct4 | 06/03/2016 | 06/06/2016

The above is dummy data.  But lets say I have 10k lines for my input data.  For my output, given a specific day I want to look at the input data and return the number of signups for that particular day. What I want to achieve is something like this:

#### SignUpDay | Count

06/01/2016 | 3

06/02/2016 | 0

06/03/2016 | 1

I know I could probably do something like this in R, but I'm working within what I have right now, which is excel.  Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Version is Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

With Excel's FREQUENCY() and an Array formula:

Assuming

- your sheet is set up with AccountNames in A2:A100
- your SignupDates are stored in B2:B100
- the current Date you want to subset for is in F2

then enter:
   `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(IF(B$2:B$100=F2,A$2:A$100,""),IF(B$2:B$100=F2,A$2:A$100,""),0),MATCH(IF(B$2:B$100=F2,A$2:A$100,""),IF(B$2:B$100=F2,A$2:A$100,""),0))>0,1))-1`

and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter this as an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Your formula does not seem to return the desired results.  Using it on the posted data, with `6/1/16` as the date, it returns the array `{2;2;1;2;2;0}`

Comment: You are correct, this requires an array formula. I guess I should not answer SO questions after midnight..

Comment: I provided a new solution.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the last two entries, the results are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

With your list of sequential dates in, for example, `F2:Fn`, you may try this **array-entered** formula:

```
G2:  =SUM(1/COUNTIF(AccountName,AccountName)*(SignUpDay=F2))
```

---

`AccountName` and `SignUpDay` should refer only to the existing data range (no blanks).  If there are blanks, a more complex formula would be required.  If you use a table, with structured addressing, the names can adjust automatically.

Also, the formula assumes that the same account will not sign up on more than one day.  If that might be the case, a more complex formula would be required.

eg:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(SignUpTable[[AccountName ]],SignUpTable[[AccountName ]])*(SignUpTable[ [ SignUpDay ] ]=F2))
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
 while hitting .  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **`{...}`** around the formula.

[image]

**EDIT:**  If your data does not fit into the above constraints, I would suggest one of the solutions linked to by @pnuts, in his comments, where you add an additional column to your data with the formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)
```

and then construct a Pivot table with `SignUpDay` in the Rows area, and this new column in the Values area.  A disadvantage of the Pivot Table solution is that dates with zero signups will not be represented in the table.

In Excel 2013+ it is possible to generate Unique Counts in the Values area, but you mentioned you are using Excel 2010, so that is not a possibility.

Comment: agreed, my formula pulled all the values including duplicates. thanks!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This doesn't work - enter ("acct3","06/03/2016","asdf") as an additional entry

Comment: It's because Sum() adds up fractionals which only sum up to the correct count if you don't filter any values out

Comment: @UlliSchmid  You have posed an example where the same account signs up on two different days.

Comment: I guess you're right, for this specific application the formula is correct. It just won't work for the general case, if you want to subset by some criterion that is independent from the "unique" key.